# How to insert multiple columns value under a single column and separate the column name?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In the database there is a table

```
   Name | id  | Yearly_Profit | Yearly_Loss | Monthly_Profit | Monthly_loss

   Alex   1     10                  20           30             40

    Ben    2     100                200           300            400
```

The output table will be like this

```
    Name | id  | Profit | Loss | Type 
     Alex   1     10       20    Yearly  
     Ben    2    100       200    Yearly 
     Alex   1     30       40     Monthly
     Ben    2    300       400    Monthly
```

How can I do this?
Is this something like pivot or other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query would work for you, in this specific scenario.

```
SELECT
   Name,
   ID,
   Yearly_Profit AS 'Profit', 
   Yearly_Loss AS 'Loss',
   'Yearly' AS 'Type'
FROM Table

UNION ALL

SELECT
   Name,
   ID,
   Monthly_Profit AS 'Profit', 
   Monthly_Loss AS 'Loss',
   'Monthly' AS 'Type'
FROM Table
ORDER BY 5
```

But, if you'd have multiple columns in your table then you'd probably have to use a [UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You could use unpivot, but union all would be the simplest solution for you.

```
select Name, id, Yearly_Profit as Profit, Yearly_Loss as Loss, 'Yearly' as Type
from your_table
union all
select Name, id, Monthly_Profit , Monthly_loss, 'Monthly'
from your_table
```